# Is the ring $\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ integrally closed?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

I am trying to understand if the ring $\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ in integrally closed (into its field of fractions), but I have no idea about how to proceed. All I have tried until now has failed. Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field of fractions is $\mathbb{C}(t)$. The element $t$ is integral because it is a root of $x^2-t^2$. But $t \notin \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$. In fact, the integral closure is $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

Comment: Thanks! I was about to edit the question because I noticed that you can do a similar thing with $(t^3/t^2)^2-t^2=0$.

Comment: And by "similar" you mean "same".

Comment: Yep. By the way, how do you prove that the integral closure is $\mathbb{C}[t]$? One inclusion is obvious, but I'm having problems with the other one...

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is integrally closed (since it is UFD).